# Why do I get IndexError: list index out of range when I can print the whole list and see for myself that my index is within range?

Tags: python, list, function, indexing, while-loop

new to Python here. I want to make a function that takes a string composed of numbers and convert it to a list made up of its digits.

```
def AmbiguousEncoding(message): 
    digits = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(message):
        x = int(message[i])
        digits.append(x)
        i += 1

    return digits
```

For `message = "112935"` I get `[1, 1, 2, 9, 3, 5]`. However, something strange happens when I want to return a specific element of a set using its index. If I `return digits[0]` I get `1` as expected. But for `digits[1]` (or any index aside from `0` and `-1`) I get this error:

```
Syntax error
Traceback (most recent call last):
line 9:, in AmbiguousEncoding
    return digits[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Why doesn't it return 1? As you can see from returning the entire list, 1,2,3,4 and 5 are valid indices. Why does it return an error?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: By any chance, when you are testing the digits[1], the string you are testing is empty? Because your code is working fine, unless the message entering is empty.

Comment: why does your traceback say SyntaxError? You did not provide the full traceback which would have indicated how you called the function.

Comment: @Walter_Ritzel nope, I test the same string, "112935". I actually don't enter the string myself, I only code at CodeFights.com where they give challenges for you to solve and tests to check if your code is working fine. message: "112935" is one of the tests, I don't manually enter it.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I only code at CodeFights.com. That's the full text of the error message that I got. So is it possible to assume that the error is in how CodeFights.com calls the function?

Comment: It seems like you changed your code, compared to what you posted, when you got the error. Was the change from `return digits` to `return digits[1]` the only change you made in your code?

Comment: Does this website provide the input or do you provide the input?

Comment: @Dzhao Yup, that's the only change. And yes, the website is the one that provides the input. We have to make a function where the function's and arguments' names are exactly the same as specified in the challenge/problem. Then they substitute the arguments with different values as tests.

Comment: Well that solves it. Look at Walter_Ritzel's comment. You can't assume that the input will be a string with two chars. Your code fails when the website's input is a string like `""` or `"a"` So sometimes when you want to return `digits[1]` your digits list just isn't that long.

Comment: @Dzhao I don't understand. The website provides me with the same input string, "112935", every time. Even if I change my code that input string (the argument for the function) doesn't change.

Comment: Ok nevermind then.

Comment: The code in the question doesn't include `return digits[1]` as shown in the error you get, so it's impossible to understand what is failing where. Please include the exact code that fails or better, a minimal reproduction of the issue you face. My bet would be either that your `return digits[1]` happens somewhere before the loop is done building `digits` (e.g. from inside the list, because of an indentation error), or that the input you claim to get is not the input you actually process (e.g. you're given a one-digit string and fail on that).

Comment: @Avish I only changed the `return digits` line to `return digits[1]`, nothing else in the code was changed. I checked the indentation, it's not the problem.

Comment: What everyone is telling you is that you are claiming the basic language features are failing, without providing any evidence whatsoever, other than "I know I did it right".  Nobody believes you because we've all thought the same thing then found out with a debugger, no, I did something silly.  Everyone does it, so have you.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Not really, as I've said I'm new at Python so I was just asking if there's something wrong in my syntax etc. I've provided everything that I can provide in the question.

Comment: I've managed to produce a workaround. It's not very elegant, but it serves my purpose. Instead of replacing `return digits` with `return digits[2]` I can introduce a new list right before the return line `y = digits[2:3]` then `return sum(y)`. For some reason, `return y[0]` also results in a list index out of range error. The same input string (112935) was used.